# understanding asynchronous vs synchronous javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

i understand that sync is blocking and only one thing can run at a time etc

and asynch can let other things run at the same time

im still confused a little bit though. if someone does a callback or api request using a promise or async/await then the code still has to wait for it to be returned before I can do anything with it? struggling to see how that is diff to synch

in this asynch code:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const response = await axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2')
  console.log(response);
}
```

i still have to wait for the 2nd line (const response) to complete before logging it or terminating the function. how is that different to synchronous?

Comment: `and asynch can let other things run at the same time` nope. Only one thing runs at a time.

Comment: @JonasW. so whats the point in asynch then?

Comment: *"i still have to wait for the 2nd line (const response) to complete before logging it or terminating the function"* Yes, but the browser ain't frozen while it's waiting. it can do other things in the meantime and come back to this function as soon as your ajax-request has returned.

Comment: @Thomas yeh but my point is not that many more other things. most websites will show a spinner to indicate it's doing something. i guess that is doing async but hardly like you can do loads of other things whilst waiting in practice

Answer (score 2):

> i understand that sync is blocking and only one thing can run at a time etc

That's JavaScript in general.

> and asynch can let other things run at the same time

Async code can be put aside while it waits for non-JavaScript stuff to happen (like an HTTP response arriving) letter other JavaScript code run in the meantime.

> i still have to wait for the 2nd line (const response) to complete before logging it or terminating the function. how is that different to synchronous?

While you are waiting **inside** `componentDidMount` for the HTTP response before calling `console.log`, other code **outside** `componentDidMount` can continue running.

```js
async function doAsync() {
    const x = await waitForIt();
    console.log("This is x", x);
}

function waitForIt() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve("one second later");
        }, 1000);
    });
}

console.log("Before doAsync");
doAsync();
console.log("After doAsync");
```

Comment: ok sure, but what other code would still run? normally a spinner would be on the screen indicating that the api call is being made and that the user needs feedback to not bounce from the page?

Comment: "but what other code would still run? " — Whatever code you want to run.

Comment: "normally a spinner would be on the screen indicating that the api call is being made" — The code to add that spinner to the DOM and allow the browser to repaint the screen so it shows up would be one thing you could do. You might also have buttons elsewhere on the screen that the user could click to do stuff. The list is endless.

Comment: yeh i partially agree. but clearly the fact the spinner is there indicates users cant do that much more. not sure of any websites where if you make a request/login/search etc you can do other things except see a loading screen until it completes. but i guess you couldn't do the loading if it was synch

Comment: Showing a spinner and not giving the user anything else to do on the page is the author's design decision, not the solve purpose of async stuff.

Comment: @TheDecimator You don't understand the implications of single-threaded. With sync code waiting, the whole page would be frozen *(at least that's how it used to be)*. The browser would not repaint the screen. No spinner would appear, let alone spin. All these things would be waiting for your function to return and for the JS to terminate

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is based on a so called `Never Blocking Event Model`, meaning that the execution of tasks will never stop. As mentioned in the other answer, JS in general synchronus.

The processing of code in JS is easy: process everything that can be processed without waiting time; when you meet an async task or in general something that requires waiting (e.g: `setTimeout(function, timeout)`) it is pushed on `Queue of messages`. Say for instance an `http` request is done. The message is pushed to the queue, but JS continues executing the code that follows. But since JS is single-threaded, who handles the `http` request? It is handled by the underlying engine. As this task is external to JS it is out of it its scope, and there is no way to know when it completes. For this purpose once the underlying engine finishes the task, it will execute a callback function to notify that that the task is completed.

This is roughly what happens in your example.